# Binding Text Property in Autocomplete Combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, wpf-controls, binding

could someone help me to solve an issue with combobox behaviour. Here is my combobox control (WPF):

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="6,0,6,6" Name="comboBoxRegionTown" IsEditable="True" IsTextSearchEnabled="True"  PreviewKeyUp="comboBoxRegionTown_PreviewKeyUp" IsTextSearchCaseSensitive="False" />
```

The idea is to make it autocomplete (IsEditable="True" IsTextSearchEnabled="True"). So then I typу any text into combobox it shows some results from database.

Here is a code of comboBoxRegionTown_PreviewKeyUp event (C#):

```
  private void comboBoxRegionTown_PreviewKeyUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBoxRegionTown.Text))
        {
            comboBoxRegionTown.ItemsSource = _br.GetQuery(x => x.Name.Contains(comboBoxRegionTown.Text) && x.RegionTypeId == (int)RegionType.Town).ToList();
            comboBoxRegionTown.IsDropDownOpen = true;
        }
        else
        {
            comboBoxRegionTown.ItemsSource = null;
        }
    }
```

So that works fine for me, but then I click to any found item in combobox it puts into ComboBox.Text property the type of my selected object (in this case - Region). Of course I can override ToString() method for my Region object and set there its public property Name and this solution works fine, but I think the best way is to find how to bind selected item into Text property of my combobox. Is there any way to do this?

I've already tryed to ind Text="{Binding Path=Name}" and/or SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Name}" but in these cases just always get empty Text. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is set the `ItemTemplate` for your ComboBox, but if you just want to display a single property there's an easier way: set `DisplayMemberPath="Name"` in the ComboBox and it'll generate the correct template for you.

Comment: great! DisplayMemberPath="Name" works like a charm. But as I got I cannot use both DisplayMemberPath and ItemTemplate at the same time?

Comment: No - an ItemTemplate will override the DisplayMemberPath.  Basically using DisplayMemberPath will create a template hat is a TextBlock bound to your chosen property.